# Break in new line CSS

Tags: html, css, chat, break, lines

I'm doing a Facebook-Like chat. The problem is that the text is making a horizontal scroll and I dont want to. The original site is http://live-pin.com/ and there you can see the code. Please help me ;)

**EDIT**: You don't need to signup, you just click on System_MSG bar under the bottom right corner. Thanks for helping

[image: No like breaking]

Comment: If you really want someone to help you, you should provide a way to test your code that does not involve signing up for your service.

Comment: You dont need to signup, just try by clicking on system_msg

Comment: Please update your question with the mark-up and CSS for the chat box

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I didn't know which part of the page was being tested.

Comment: Post your code here, not just a link to your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you use non-breakable spaces (&nbsp). Use normal spaces instead and the text will display correctly:

Change this:

```
Hi&nbsp;visitor.&nbsp;We&nbsp;suggest&nbsp;you&nbsp;to&nbsp;sign in
```

to this

```
Hi visitor. We suggest you to sign in
```

Comment: Thank you very much, any other suggestion?

Comment: If you MUST use nonbreakable spaces, you can add "overflow:hidden" style to the parent DIV, but the text that does not fit won't display at all.

Comment: That's the best way. Why would you want to use nbsp's anyways?

Comment: Maybe because of escape problems? That's what happened directly on JSON file on my script.

Comment: Well, if you just need to process the data with NBSPs, you can get rid of them when putting them into the page using javascript.